# typescript expended object show only firs added

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = {
  num1 : 'string',
}
const obj2 = {
  num2 : 1234
}
let a = {
  ...obj,
}
a = {
  ...a,
  ...obj2,
}
a.num1 // ok
a.num2 // error
```

Object `a` contains first element num1 and dont show the second num2
in real code the obj and obj2 is complex and not same

[image]

Comment: If you want to be more type safe - avoid mutations

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of `a`, the type of `a` is limited to

```
const a: {
     num1: string;
}
```

While assigning `{ ...a, ...obj2}` to `a` can satisfy this restriction condition, but when the variable `a` is used, its type is still the type when it was originally defined, so It will throw an exception, maybe you can try

```js
const obj = {
   num1:'string',
}
const obj2 = {
   num2: 1234
}
const a = {
   ...obj,
}
const c = {
   ...a,
   ...obj2,
}
c.num1 // ok
c.num2 // ok
```

[online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGYCuAtgIwwBcMA5NAE4CWYA5hQDSYC%20moksCiATKgzZchAeSJ8AzABZ2ncNBgBDQVhwA6Tb1Ycui4KuGb1S1hq1I%20OzuvzEYAegdwA1jbsCnroA)

Comment: Also, TS does not work well with mutations

Comment: thank for solution !

i make 'a' as let because 'a = {
  ...a,
  ...obj2,
}' run in loop
and a returned from function in the end